# How do the second person present forms of *ser* divert from Latin?

Tags: etimología, conjugación, latín

I noticed that the 2nd person of indicative present forms are a bit strange compared to Latin.

- *sum* → soy
- *es* → e**r**es (French *es*, Italian *sei*, Portuguese *és*)
- *est* → es
- *sumus* → somos
- *estis* → s**o**is (French *êtes*, Italian *siete*)
- *sunt* → son

The *tú* and *vosotros* forms don't quite match Latin. Can anyone explain how they came to be?

Comment: We we all want to find a logic in etymology. Unfortunately etymologic doesn't mean to be logic, and words creation and evolution is at people's whim, many times depending on confusions and lack of understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Eres* most likely<sup>1</sup> comes from the 2nd person singular future active indicative of sum, *eris* ("you will be").

*Sois* comes from the Late Latin form **sutis* (formed by analogy to *sumus*)<sup>2</sup>:

> ESTIS (re-placed by *SUTIS, analogical to SUMUS) > OSp. *sodes* > ModSp. *sois*

---

<sup>1. [*On the Origin of Spanish eres*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/475003), Griffin (1994)</sup>
<sup>2. [*The Origin of Spanish "ser": A Phonosyntactic Analysis*](https://search.proquest.com/openview/2c6c45288813fd5bd7e9e1098c878fa3/1), Joel Rini (1997)</sup>

<sup>Note that [some other tenses of *ser*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27254/are-the-english-words-essence-and-essential-related-to-the-spanish-word-ser/27262#27262) (future indicative, present subjunctive, conditional, imperative, infinitive, past participle, gerund) aren't related to *sum* at all, and are inherited from the suppletion of multiple different verbs in Latin (*ire, vadere, sedere*).</sup>

Comment: Buscando en el CORDE en textos hasta el año 1300 se encuentran 685 casos de _sodes_ por solo 63 de _sois_. Los registros no se igualan hasta el siglo XV (1401-1500): 691 casos de _sodes_ por 687 de _sois_.